# Form Authorization not working as expected. How does it works?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, asp.net-authorization, system.web

I have set `<allow Roles="Admin" />`but not set `<Deny />` tag under system.web and authorization tag but it allow all user to access Admin page.
I don't want to allow admin page except admin role user.
Can anyone help me this regards.

Comment: If you don't deny access, then why would you expect them to be able to not access it?

Answer (score 0):

You must check all possibilities.

```
1. everyone can access the site and pages by default.
2. you allow Admin.
3. everyone else is still allowed.
```

Set allow, then set deny.

```
<allow roles="Admin"/> // allow users in Admin role.
<deny users="*"/>      // deny everyone else.
```

See [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config).